# UIButton responds to UIPanGestureRecognizer on top of it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I just added a UIView with UIPanGestureRecognizer on top of my view.
The view has several UIButtons which respond to touchUpInside events.
What's weird is that ever since I brought the UIPanGestureRecognizer, when panning, if the UIButton is right underneath the "Panning view", the button would trigger which is not what I am after. 
Of course I could make a BOOL flag for "panning", so that the button won't fire, but it seems to me like bad engineering and surely something I am missing. I guess after the first touch, both views intercept the event.
Is it possible to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

use this method to differentiate `GestureRecognizer` and `Button` Acton.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I like your method, but both views are UIImageViews

Comment: ok, set different tags for imageViews and check in this method, if possible.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, so I find it hard to solve it.:) Why does my UIImageView pass the UIPanGestureRecognizer event on down the chain?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help

```
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanned:)];
- (void)handlePanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)thePanner{

    if (thePanner.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ){
       //disable button 
    }else if (thePanner.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //enable button
    }else if ( thePanner.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ){
     //enable button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort-out your problem by following two tactics:-

1)When adding the gesture in your required view, be sure that it will not added with un-required view, in this case is your UIButton, &;

2)At the method/delegate where you handle the case of detecting the gesture, ie what gesture do, before the implementation you assure that this is not the UIButton.

If you insist, I'll try for sample code.

Have a good day ahead. :)